# Get Jenkinsfile path from the pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline job where I specify a custom location of Jenkinsfile. Is there a way to retrieve the path of this Jenkinsfile from the pipeline?

Here's what I want to achieve: I have a single git repository that consists of multiple projects (monorepo). Each project has its own Jenkins multibranch pipeline build, they only differ in the name and path to Jenkinsfile. These projects build Docker images and I would like to standardize the Docker image naming by following the project path, which is the directory of Jenkinsfile. At the moment I add the name manually in the Jenkinsfile but I think it would be better if I can just retrieve this information from Jenkins.

Comment: Did you try referring to the variable "BRANCH_NAME" in the pipeline script? Not sure if that is what you're looking for ...

Comment: In the build config, i can set to use Jenkinsfile from for example `gui/Jenkinsfile`. I would like to get this `gui/Jenkinsfile` value from the pipeline, from the code I write in that `gui/Jenkinsfile`

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to get it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chadi I updated the question with what I am trying to achive

Comment: after checking some code, looks like there is no way to achieve this using what is already available. I ended up writing a plugin to do this. For those who want to do the same, look for EnvironmentContributor extension as a starting point.